# Magento discontinued products icon

Tags: products

so let's say i have a laptop in the shop, but after some time it's discontinued, but people still search for it. I've seen in couple custom made e-shops showing discontinued products after all the other products with an icon like the NEW tag on top of the picture. Is there a way to do this in magento, any scripting or an extension?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean by "discontinued" but you could add a custom attribute to the Product model  and update it with daily product imports. All you'd then have to do is update the product/product-list templates and check for that attribute and display a special icon.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom attribute for discontinued product maybe set the attribute as yes or no input.

Then you can check if this attribute is set to yes in your template files display discontinued image.